# Solve $|x| \le |x-2|$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm not sure how to go about this one. First I tried to do

$$|x| \le |x-2| \iff|x|-|x-2| \le 0 \iff |x-x+2| \le 0 \iff 2 \le 0$$

This is wrong. Can you do $|a|+|b| = |a+b|$?

Then I tried to do

$$x\le x-2 \iff 0\le-2 \iff 0\ge 2$$ Which is wrong? Then the others...

$$x\le-x+2 \iff 2x\le2 \iff x \le 1$$

$$-x \le x-2 \iff -2x \le -2 \iff x \ge 1$$
$$-x \le -x +2 \iff 0 \le 2$$

So... x=1 ? Nope.

How do I solve this?

Comment: You cannot include the second argument into the first one.

Comment: $|a|+|b|=|a+b|$ is true if and only if $a$ and $b$ are both in the same "direction."

Comment: @JMoravitz What do you mean?

Comment: @SilenceOnTheWire in the context of the real numbers, that means they are both positive or are both negative.  In the context of more complicated vector spaces, it gets more complicated but if the vector space is over the field of the real numbers that would mean that $a = kb$ where $k$ is a non-negative real number.  In the most general sense, again, they are in "the same direction."

Answer (score 1):

Since both sides are always nonnegative, you can square the given inequality in order to obtain
\begin{align*}
|x| \leq |x-2| \Longleftrightarrow x^{2} \leq (x-2)^{2} = x^{2} - 4x + 4 \Longleftrightarrow x \leq 1
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Consider the zeros of these two moduli: $0$ and $2$. They divide $\Bbb R$ into three intervals. Let $x<0$. Then $|x|=-x$ and $|x-2|=-x+2$ and the inequality is $-x\le -x+2$, so $0\le 2$, which is true, then every $x<0$ fulfils the inequality.

Consider the remaining two cases by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can start by graphing the two functions so you can visualize the solution, which is $x \leq 1$. Now, you can solve the equation by case:

Case $x \geq 2$: then the equation translates to $x \leq x - 2$, which is impossible.

Case $0 \leq x < 2$: then the equation translates to $x \leq -(x - 2) = 2 - x$, which is true only when $x \leq 1$.

Case $x < 0$: then the equation translates to $-x \leq 2 - x$, which is always true.

Thus, the solution is, indeed, $x \leq 1$.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 0):

Set $|x| = |x-2|$ first to find the only ‘break point’ at $x=1$ for the inequality. Then, pick any point on either side of $x=1$ to check,

$x<1,\>\>\>|0|< |0-2|, \>\>\> true$

$x>1,\>\>\>|2|< |2-2|, \>\>\> false$

Thus, the solution is $x\le1$.